# How to horizontally sort divs using Sortable in JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am looking to sort my divs horizontally in a container div. 
I found an [example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#sortable) on JQuery website but that is vertical sorting. I want it horizontal.

I want to do it sorting in `#sortable` `<div>`.

Will you please guide me how can I convert this vertical sorting in horizontal manner.

### CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
    #draggable1 { width: 150px; height: 35px; padding: 0.5em; }
    #draggable2 { width: 150px; height: 35px; padding: 0.5em; }
    #draggable3 { width: 150px; height: 35px; padding: 0.5em; }

    #sortable { width: 700px; height: 35px; padding: 0.5em; }
</style>
```

### JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {  
        $("#sortable").sortable({
            revert: true
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

### HTML

```
<div class="demo">
    <div id="sortable" class="ui-state-default">
        <div id = "draggable1" class="ui-state-default">Home</div>
        <div id = "draggable2" class="ui-state-default">Contact Us</div>
        <div id = "draggable3" class="ui-state-default">FAQs</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've made a small script for that in vanilla js: [dragsort.js](https://github.com/yairEO/dragsort)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can just add this CSS style:

```
#sortable>div { float: left; }
```

And they'll be horizontal and still sortable.  [You can see a demo of it in action here](http://jsfiddle.net/sP3UZ/).

Comment: This is the best answer for browser compatibility. Don't forget to style your placeholder with float:left as well. If you are adding dynamic items to your list, you may also need to manage a "clear:both" div at the bottom of your list to retain volume/height of the list itself.

Answer (score 6):

Although `float:left` works, here I would rather use `display:inline-table` for the divs, so that you don't lose the volume of your divs...

Answer (score 3):

just add to your CSS : `display: inline-block;`