# JQuery UI Sortable with Horizontal Scrolling is shifting all elements down

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I want to allow the user to sort objects left-to-right with a scroll bar.

The objects are boxes with HTML in them, including some text, not images like many of the other examples.

The problem is that as the user drags one of the objects, all the other ones shift downward during dragging.

Here's what I have:

HTML:

```
<div id="parent" class="parent">
  <div id="list" class="list">
    <div class="item">A</div>
    <div class="item">B</div>
    <div class="item">C</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
  height:64px;
  width:280px;
}
.list {
  background-color:#d0d0d0;
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow-x:scroll;
  overflow-y:hidden;
  /*text-align:left;*/
}
.item {
  background-color:#404040;
  height:40px;
  width:100px;
  margin:4px;
  cursor:pointer;
  display:inline-block;
  /*float:left;*/
  /*float:none;*/
  /*clear:both;*/
}
.placeholder {
  height:40px;
  width:20px;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:4px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
  $('#list').disableSelection().sortable({
    scroll: true,
    placeholder: 'placeholder',
    //containment:'parent',
    axis: 'x'
  });
})
```

I tried lots of different settings, and left some of them in as comments.

Best way to see the problem is here: http://jsfiddle.net/francispotter/gtKtE/

Comment: Look at http://jsfiddle.net/sP3UZ/ from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544143/how-to-horizontally-sort-divs-using-sortable-in-jquery

Comment: @mlbase75 Thanks for the response, but that doesn't address the problem. The examples in the links you provided uses float, which is fine if you want the objects to form a tiled grid. I want the items to *only* be arranged horizontally, and for the region to scroll left/right to accommodate the items. So I need to use display:inline-block.

Comment: I've been fiddling with the code, and as far as I can tell Sortable was never designed to be used horizontally. I think that the gap created at the top of your DIVs is an invisible placeholder DIV of some kind, which can't be removed without changing the jQuery UI code itself. See also http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6702

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A solution I found that works WITHOUT having to rewrite the ui library and is a clean and css fix:

```
.ui-sortable-placeholder {
  display: inline-block;
height: 1px;
}
```

Comment: I know this was a while ago but thanks - this helped me a lot
To show what you mean (and prove it works), here is a working mod of the OP's fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/q4uze/3/

Answer (score 2):

This answer is undoubtably too late to help you, but perhaps it will help others in the same situation.  I found your question a couple of days ago as I'm trying to do the same sort of thing to allow a user to reorder the "photos" on a "film strip".  The comment on your question suggesting the use of "float" rather than "inline-block" turned out to be key in finding the solution.  This led me to using a fixed-size DIV to hold the sortable items, avoiding the height change caused by word-wrapping, then adding an outer DIV with overflow-x:scroll to do the horizontal scrolling.  Enjoy!

https://jsfiddle.net/kmbro/y8ccza34/

HTML

```
<div id='scrollable'>
<div id='sortable'>
<div class='item'>Block A</div>
<div class='item'>Block B</div>
<div class='item'>Block C</div>
<div class='item'>Block D</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#scrollable {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

#sortable {
  border: dashed green;
  border-width: 6px 0;
  padding: 4px 0;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 150px;
  width:calc(4 * 200px + 1px); // 1px for dragging
}

.item {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  box-sizing: border-box; /* keep padding/border inside height/width */
  border: solid green 4px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

jQuery 2.1.3 / jQuery UI 1.11.4

```
$('#sortable').sortable({
axis: 'x',
});
```

Answer (score 1):

One answer (not elegant, but it works) proposed by a colleague is to set float:left on item, then:

```
$(function() {
  $('#list').disableSelection().sortable({
    scroll: true,
    axis: 'x',
    create: function(event, ui) {
        var $e = $(event.target);
        var width = 0;
        $e.children().each(function(){
            width += $(this).outerWidth(true);
        });
        $e.width(width);
    }
  });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is kind of a late answer, but I have been having problems with this as well. 
The fix for me was changing

```
.removeClass("ui-sortable-helper")[0];
```

to

```
.removeClass("ui-sortable-helper").html('&nbsp;')[0];
```

at line 659 in the current uncompressed version (v1.8.17).

I hope this still helps you out.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've moved on from this project (just left the bug in there). Is this a patch that should be submitted to JQuery itself?

Comment: Yes, I guess this is the patch, as I tried this in both the horizontal and vertical sortable. I'll post it on the jQuery UI site as well.

Comment: Instead of changing the source, you can use the 'start' callback as well. `start: function(event, ui) { ui.placeholder.html('&nbsp;'); }`. Don't forget to attach this to both of the connected lists.

Comment: Boo.  Don't modify core files!

Answer (score 1):

As @BertterHeide so rightly commented, the **proper** solution to this issue is to modify your `.sortable` call, adding `start: function(event, ui) { ui.placeholder.html('&nbsp;'); }`, as follows:

```
$(function() {
  $('#list').disableSelection().sortable({
    scroll: true,
    placeholder: 'placeholder',
    start: function(event, ui) { ui.placeholder.html('&nbsp;'),
    //containment:'parent',
    axis: 'x'
  });
})
```