# Issue with jQuery sortable/dragable function DIV position moves on drag

Tags: jquery, html, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm a bit new to the world of jQuery Sortable UI Plugin and I'm having a hard time figuring out why all of my div's, in a row, shift down when one of them is moved to another sort order. It seems to work fine when its a vertical list, but that won't work for this application.

I can't add images as this is my first post but basically that is it, there are no weird margins or anything set.

There are two containers that will trade information, but I don't think it makes a difference with this issue. If there is a more proper way to do this, I more then welcome suggestions.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <title>Test</title>


    </head>
    <style>

    #List1, #List2
    {
        overflow-x: scroll;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        height:85px;
        width: 700px; /* not really your css, I used it in my test case */
        white-space:nowrap;

    }

    #List1 > DIV, #List2 > DIV
    {
        display: inline-block;
        width:85px;
        height:55px; 
        border:solid thin black;
        position:inherit;
        margin:inherit;
    }
    </style>
    <body>
    <div id="List1">
        <div>test1</div>
        <div>test2</div>
        <div>test3</div>
        <div>test4</div>

    </div>

    <div id="List2">
        <div>test5</div>
        <div>test6</div>
        <div>test7</div>
        <div>test8</div>
        <div>test9</div>
        <div>test10</div>

    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

        <script>
    $(function(){
        var sortlists = $("#List1, #List2").sortable(
        {
            appendTo: 'body',
            tolerance: 'pointer',
            connectWith: '#List1, #List2',
            revert: 'invalid',
            forceHelperSize: true,
            helper: 'original',
            scroll: true,
            cursorAt: { top: 0, left: 0 } 
        });
        $("#List1, #List2").disableSelection();

    });


    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Why do you have twice closing tags for `<body>` and `<html>`?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7275374/jquery-ui-sortable-with-horizontal-scrolling-is-shifting-all-elements-down

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this:

```
.ui-sortable-placeholder{
    display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vGyQ6/  It looks like jQuery-UI adds a div for that little guy and for some reason display: hidden is not being respected.

Comment: I modified the jquery library and replaced 

.removeClass("ui-sortable-helper")[0];

with

.removeClass("ui-sortable-helper").html('&nbsp;')[0];

And it seems to the trick, im going to do some reading to try and understand how this will work for my needs. Thanks!